# Who is Queen Brijeena, the subject of a famous chavittu nadakam?

Tags: oral-tradition, opera

[*Chavittu nadakam*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chavittu_Nadakam) is a Christian-origin dance form from Kerala, India. It's quite similar to the European opera, though *chavittu nadakam* involves a lot of dancing.
The dance is accompanied by archaic Malayalam/Tamil songs, called *nadakam*s, written down in poem form.

One such *nadakam* is the *Brijeena Charitham*, literally *The Legend of Brijeena*. According to the Wikipedia page on *chavittu nadakam*, the title is translated to *Life of Queen Brijeena*. This is apparently the costume used by the character of Queen Brijeena.
[image: Queen Brijeena]

By PrinceMathewVillarvattam [Public domain], from Wikimedia Commons

Which queen is this? I cannot find any reference to a "Queen Brijeena" online.

Comment: Could it be a corruption of Virginia (a name connected to Queen Elizabeth)?

Comment: @ba Quite possibly. A search for "Queen Brijeena" on Google does show one result featuring Queen Elizabeth II. I dismissed it since this *nadakam* was written over two centuries ago.

Comment: I was actually thinking of [Elizabeth I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_I_of_England). It seems that Virginia isn't an actual epithet of hers, though. I wonder if the content of the *nadakam* matches some story about her, but I can't find any details online to compare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be St. Brigit who was revered in a Jesuit church in Lisbon around 1587. Dr. Christophe Vielle mentions this in a KCHR lecture.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you provide more context on how your answers might be correct? Relevant quotes from the lecture you mention might be a good start. Also take some time to have a look at our [tour] and [help] to get better understanding of the community.

Comment: Five years late as it is, I am now convinced that this is indeed the correct answer.